# Commands not available when using SSH via circleCi

Tags: git, ubuntu, ssh, circleci

I have the following job in my circleci config.yml:

```
  deploy:
    machine:
      enabled: true
    steps:
      - run:
          name: Deploy Over SSH
          command: |
            ssh $SSH_USER@$SSH_HOST "
              source .zshrc
              cd ~/blogs-cms 
              git pull
              export NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=2048
              yarn install
              yarn build
              pm2 restart blogs-cms"
```

I'm attempting to ssh into my ubuntu server and run the above commands. This gives me the following error:

```
Warning: Permanently added '**************' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
zsh:4: command not found: git pull
yarn install v1.22.17
$ strapi build
Building your admin UI with development configuration ...
ℹ Compiling Webpack
✔ Webpack: Compiled successfully in 2.83m
Admin UI built successfully
Done in 178.22s.
```

Everything works fine apart from the `git pull` command. Yet if I actually paste the command:

```
ssh $SSH_USER@$SSH_HOST "
  source .zshrc
  cd ~/blogs-cms 
  git pull
  export NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=2048
  yarn install
  yarn build
  pm2 restart blogs-cms"
```

Then everything executes fine, so the git issue only appears to happen in CircleCi, can someone please shed some light on what this might be?

Comment: Making the first command be `declare -p PATH` (or whatever its zsh equivalent is, if the default remote shell is in fact zsh) might be a place to start. Note that `echo "$PATH"` is trickier to get right, because you need to ensure that it's evaluated by the remote shell and not the local one; depending on the execution flow there might be some escaping needed.

Comment: Also, I really recommend against sourcing dotfiles in a noninteractive script -- you're throwing variables into play that don't need to be there. If you _need_ something that's set in .zshrc, move it into a separate file, and make both .zshrc and your script source that file; that way when the remote user changes their dotfiles for a better interactive experience they don't risk breaking your script.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks :) I'm used to actually sshing into a box and just running commands myself, I've never done it this way before, I'm not entirely sure what you mean by making `declare -p PATH` as the first command, that doesn't seem to fix any issues :-/

Comment: The point of `declare -p PATH` is that it prints the remote PATH so we can see if the directory containing the git executable is listed. It's not supposed to fix anything itself, it's supposed to provide enough information to let us diagnose the problem and determine what a fix would be.

Comment: Similarly, the other thing you'll want to add to your preamble is `set -x` to enable trace-level logging from the shell. If something being sourced from your zshrc is messing you up, the xtrace logs will let us know.

Comment: (For `declare -p PATH` to be maximally useful, you'll want to compare its output between the noninteractive shell where things break and an interactive shell where they work -- again, translating that command to an appropriate equivalent where the active shell isn't bash).